# Access data generated by a middleware in an operation hook

Tags: javascript, loopbackjs

I want to create a middleware which gather all current user info needed to perform ACL operation in my model's operation hooks.

- Creating the middleware or gathering data is not an issue.
- My middleware is called just before the `loopback#rest` middleware.

**How can I make available data from my middleware into a model operation hook?**

(can I access the `req` param in the operation hook? can I use the context?)

Sample code (not complete, just to illustrate, my acl list and need is far more complex):

*middleware:*

```
module.exports = function() {
  return function myMiddleware(req, res, next) {
    // extracts the token from the request
    // extracts the user from the token
    // fetch in the database informations about user 

    user.findById({id: userId} , function (result) {

      currentUserData = {
        id: userId,
        companyRead: result.companyRead,
        companyWrite: result.companyWrite,
        companyRestrictList : result.companyRestictList
      }

      next();
    });
  }
}
```

*Model:*

```
module.exports = function (Company) {

  Company.observe('access', function (ctx, next) {

    if ( !currentUserData.companyRead )
      return next('error 401')

      // hook find to only display granted companies
      ctx.query.where = {
        "id": {inq: currentUserData.companyRestrictList }
      }

      next();
  });
}
```

My `currentUserData` object is created in the middleware.
How can I access it in the model hook?

Comment: You should probably provide some code or at least request params so that we can help you..

Comment: you're right. code added!